# in python 2.7 order of iterate with for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a question about the order of iteration in a list when I use a for loop. 
I am trying to go through a list of pairs and do some operations on them.  For example consider this code:

```
for j in my EdgeList:    #Edgelist= [(4,5),(5,6)]
    mylist.append(j)
```

However, I thought when I use this code the value of j will be the first pair (4,5) in the first loop and then it will take the second pair (5,6) on the second loop. When I debug the program line by line though, I noticed that some times it takes the last pair instead of the first and on another debug run it takes the first pair first. I want to know if that is normal for python or not.

Comment: The elements in a list are always iterated over in order.  If you think you've seen them being iterated over in any other order when using a standard `for` loop, you have done something wrong.

Comment: Are you *sure* `EdgeList` is a list and not, say, a `set`?

Comment: I just noticed in my debugger that the EdgeList is like this set([(4,5),(5,6)]) would that be the reason of this problem?

Comment: @NadaAlzaben Yes, absolutely.  Sets don't have a defined order.

Comment: thank you @brianpck

Answer (score 1):

IF `EdgeList` is a List, then iteration will always start from the first index and go to the last. These two should output the same result:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
# Don't use a while loop like this… please.
>>> while i < len(l):
...    print(l[i])
...    i+= 1
# outputs 1 2 3 4 5 separated by newlines
>>> for item in l:
...    print(item)
# outputs 1 2 3 4 5 separated by newlines
```

There are times when EdgeList is not actually a list, however. `Set`s, for example don't guarantee order, neither are the keys of dictionaries. This means `{'f':1,'g':2}.keys()` does not *have* to return a sequence in the order `1, 2`

Comment: thank you. how can convert a set to a list? so that i can guarantee the order. i am getting the list of edges from a NetworkX function nx.minimum_edge_cut(G,source,sink) so i need to convert then the set to a list to deal with it in order

Comment: @NadaAlzaben No need to convert into list, do a sorted(s), where s is your set. Remember to store the result as this is not done in-place.

Comment: @themistoklik when i use sorted(s) will the for loop iterate in order then?

Comment: Yes it will, it will produce a list and will iterate over it in order since it's sorted (asc).